# How to query an STI-driven model using nested associations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My requirement is to write a query to retrieve records based of a model on STI based on the nested associations of the model.

Here’s what my modeling looks like:

```ruby
class Loan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :borrower
end

class BusinessLoan < Loan
  belongs_to :business, inverse_of: :business_loans
end

class HousingLoan < Loan
end

class Borrower < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :loans
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Business < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :business_loans, inverse_of: :business
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  # COLUMN city, :string
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I would like to write to retrieve the list of all loans whose business or borrower is in a particular city.

Here’s what I have at the moment:

```ruby
cities = ["New York", "Washington"]

query_string = [
                Loan.select(:id).joins(borrower: :address).where(city: cities).to_sql,
                BusinessLoan.select(:id).joins(business: :address).where(city: cities).to_sql
               ].join(" UNION ")
Loan.where(id: Loan.find_by_sql(query_string))
```

*I require the result as an ActiveRecord relation hence the last query*

Is there a better way to write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a way to directly achieve this without writing a few new scopes in the associated models. Rails does not permit any operations in scopes that are not possible on the model on which the scopes are initiated.

You can however still solve the problem to yield a single query as follows:

1. Define `from_cities` scopes in `Borrower` and `Business` as shown below:

```ruby
scope :from_cities, ->(cities) { joins(:address).where("addresses.city IN (?)", cities) }
```

2. Define `from_cities` in Loan to use these new scopes:

```ruby
scope :from_cities, ->(cities) do
  where(borrower_id: Borrower.from_cities(cities)).
    or(where(business_id: Business.from_cities(cities)))
end
```